# JSchema.Parse method throws an exception , when ussed in server side asp.net code

Tags: json.net

Attempt by method Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema.Parse(System.String) to access method Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ValidationUtils.ArgumentNotNull(System.Object, System.String)' failed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like version mismatch between Newtonsoft.Json and NewtonSoft.Json.Schema. Newtonsoft.Json.Schema 1.0.6 relies on Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8. Above mentioned exception will occur only at run time.